# Where is pi defined in mathjs?

Tags: mathjs

I have a custom bundle for `mathjs` that looks something like so:

```
var core = require('mathjs/core');
var math = core.create();
math.import(require('mathjs/lib/type'));
math.import(require('mathjs/lib/function/arithmetic'));
math.import(require('mathjs/lib/function/trigonometry'));
math.import(require('mathjs/lib/expression'));
```

which I then export. If I then try `math.eval('pi')`, I get an Exception:

```
Exception: Error: Undefined symbol pi
```

I *don't* see this error if I import the entire `mathjs` library but, then, that rather defeats the purpose of the small custom bundle.

**Question**: What is the minimal import so that `math.eval('pi')` returns 3.14...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var core = require('mathjs/core');
var math = core.create();
math.import(require('mathjs/lib/type'));
math.import(require('mathjs/lib/expression'));
math.import(require('mathjs/lib/constants'));

console.log(math.eval('pi')) // 3.141592653589793
```

See the *constants* module in the [github repository](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/blob/master/lib/constants.js) of mathjs.

The value of PI is taken from the standard, built-in Javascript object **Math**. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI).

Comment: Thanks! I'm struggling a bit to see how I missed that. :)